# How can I set a ref to the value of an ajax call without triggering @update:modelValue in vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a checkbox that when clicked triggers an ajax call using the `@update:modelValue` syntax in the template. However whenever this page loads the ajax call gets called.

This is happening because when the `setup()` function runs I set the `isPushNotificationChecked` ref and then I update it in the onMounted function to be the response of a different ajax call.

Here is the code:

```
<template>
  <ion-checkbox
    slot="start"
    v-model="isPushNotificationChecked"
    @update:modelValue="updatePushNotifications"
  ></ion-checkbox>
</template>

<script>
import {
  IonCheckbox,
} from "@ionic/vue";
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import useToast from "@/services/toast";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Settings",
  components: {
    IonCheckbox,
  },
  setup() {
    const isPushNotificationChecked = ref(false);

    onMounted(async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("settings");
      // Since I change the value here @update:modelValue in template triggers updatePushNotifications
      isPushNotificationChecked.value = response.data.notifications_enabled;
    });

    // This gets triggered on page load when it shouldn't
    const updatePushNotifications = async () => {
      if (isPushNotificationChecked.value) {
        axios.post("notifications/enable");
      } else {
        axios.post("notifications/disable");
      }

      useToast().success("Push notifications updated");
    };

    return {
      isPushNotificationChecked,
      updatePushNotifications,
    };
  },
});
</script>
```

How can I go about setting the ref value to be the response of an ajax call without removing the behaviour of clicking the checkbox and triggering the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to instead use a watcher that is initialised in the `onMounted()` function and remove the `@update:modelValue="updatePushNotifications"`:

```
<template>
  <ion-checkbox
    slot="start"
    v-model="isPushNotificationChecked"
  ></ion-checkbox>
</template>

<script>
import {
  IonCheckbox,
} from "@ionic/vue";
import { defineComponent, ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";
import useToast from "@/services/toast";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Settings",
  components: {
    IonCheckbox,
  },
  setup() {
    const isPushNotificationChecked = ref(false);

    onMounted(async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("settings");
      isPushNotificationChecked.value = response.data.notifications_enabled;

      // Watcher setup after ajax call.
      watch(isPushNotificationChecked, (value) => {
        if (value) {
          axios.post("notifications/enable");
        } else {
          axios.post("notifications/disable");
        }

        useToast().success("Push notifications updated");
      });
    });

    return {
      isPushNotificationChecked
    };
  },
});
</script>
```